# Data recovery on bitlocker drives?

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I have a Windows 8 drive that had the GPT Protective partition converted to MBR in an attempt to read it on another system.  The user then did not see the drive yet still and converted it back to GPT. It appears in the process that the volume data is missing / destroyed and data has not been recoverable.  Are there any utilities or methodologies that will facilitate data recover or rebuilding of the original partition data in such a scenario?

This was a Windows 8 volume from a new HP computer that appears to have, by default, secured the volume as the drive was not even readable in another Windows 8.x installation.

Comment: Try this? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17294

Comment: So yes, I have tried this, however the volume is not being mounted. I see "Disk 1" and it is online, but according to Disk Management, it is unallocated.  Further I'm not seeing an option to get the GUID of this disk so that I can give `repair-bd.exe` a chance to take a look at it.